# What differences come out between defining functions as static members and free?

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Element {
    void SetVisible(bool) { cout << "Called SetVisible on Element" << endl; }
};

struct ElementQuery {
    ElementQuery(Element * e) : element(e) { }
    Element * Get() const { return element; }
    Element * element;
};

namespace A {

static void SetVisible(ElementQuery const& element, bool show) {
    cout << "Called SetVisible on ElementQuery" << endl;
    SetVisible(element.Get(), show);
}

static void SetVisible(Element * element, bool show) {
    element->SetVisible(show);
}

};

int main() {
    Element * e = new Element();
    ElementQuery q(e);
    A::SetVisible(q, true);
    delete e;
    return 0;
}
```

When run, program fails because of infinite recursion in call `SetVisible(element.GetFirst(), show)`. As I presume that is so because of function `SetVisible(Element * element, bool show)` is not declared yet at the time of call though it  fits overload resolution better.

But when I change `namespace A` to `struct A`, recompile and run, everything works fine. Program prints two lines to `cout` and ends gracefully.

My question is: why does the second call "sees" second declaration of `SetVisible` and what are the differences between such declarations?

Comment: Members declared anywhere in a class are visible everywhere in the class. I don't think there's anything more to it than that.

Comment: Great example why constructor should be explicit. If ElementQuery(Element * e) were explicit the code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Most upvoted answer to question Charles Bailey referenced made it clear to me.  If you make the constructor explicit that Tomek suggests and switch the order of the SetVisible functions in namespace A then it works

Comment: @wreckgar23 @CharlesBailey Ok, now I see, could you elaborate a short answer? And point me what is the reason behind that the scope of `struct` extended such way.

Comment: @Keynslug I think the referenced answer I mentioned b4 puts it best as to why this is for structs - it's for "allowing references to members of classes defined later".  Which begs the question "why not allow this for everything, not just structs/classes?"  Someone clever than me could give you a more authoritative answer, but I'd suggest it'd be for historical and/or compiler performance reasons.  What if some existing code relied on an overload not yet being visible, for example?

Comment: @wreckgar23: I suspect the feature was added for classes because it's expected that a class is *reasonably* small compared with an entire program, and so it's *reasonably* non-confusing for things to be in scope prior to their declaration. The old reason for not having it, inherited from C, is that it would be confusing for the compiler to do multiple passes, but by the time of C++ it's more about confusing the programmer.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks, it seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the namespace is processed in order and there exists a conversion between Element and ElementQuery (because your constructor is not explicit).

Here is the corrected code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Element {
    void SetVisible(bool) { cout << "Called SetVisible on Element" << endl; }
};

struct ElementQuery {
    explicit ElementQuery(Element * e) : element(e) { }
    Element * Get() const { return element; }
    Element * element;
};

namespace A {

static void SetVisible(Element * element, bool show) {
    cout << "Called A::SetVisible on Element" << endl;
    element->SetVisible(show);}

static void SetVisible(ElementQuery const& element, bool show) {
    cout << "Called A::SetVisible on ElementQuery" << endl;
    SetVisible(element.Get(), show);
}

};

int main() {
    Element * e = new Element();
    ElementQuery q(e);
    A::SetVisible(q, true);
    delete e;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code should not be compiled at all. Because this call:
    SetVisible(element.Get(), show);
The $void SetVisible(Element * element, bool show) is not visible at moment call. You need to move this function before $void SetVisible(ElementQuery const& element, bool show).

Comment: You could try that. It compiles because `ElementQuery` has implicit constructor that takes `Element *` as a parameter.